# Exclude Android build while building Xmarin.Forms sln

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, msbuild

Currently I installed a Mac pipeline agent without android tools, because I intended to use it for iOS only. My question is how to filter the Xamarin.Form solution not to build Android because it fails on this environment.

I'm wondering if there is a way for exclude the android part in the Build Xamarin azure task. I'm asking a way of doing it through: msbuild /t:restore;build /avoid:Android.csproj;Android.Binding.csproj or something alike...

Comment: create a build configuration that does not include the Android project.  Build Configurations are standard tooling for Visual Studio projects, including Xamarin.

Comment: @Jason, that's great, could you gave me an example or al least a reference on how to do it?

Comment: Please don't use `/t:Restore;Build`. use `/restore /t:Build` instead

Comment: Thanks Ullrich, although that doesn't solve my situation is nice to know best practices. Anyways could you explain the difference?

Comment: It is theoretically possible to run both a restore and build in the same invocation (/t:Restore;Build) but it is unsafe as MSBuild may cache project files and not see changes made by a NuGet restore. The /restore option will clear all the affected caches before resuming with the normal build.

Answer (score 1):

in VS Mac (should be similar, but possibly with different menu paths, on PC) select `Solution --> Options` in the Solution Explorer.  Under `Build/Configurations` create a new config (or copy an existing one).  Then select `Configuration Mappings`, select the config you just created, and Disable the projects that you want to exclude.

When setting up your build pipeline you should have to specify which configuration you want to use.